# How is the OR boolean in find command?

Tags: find

How do you tell the find command to find string a OR b?

Like: find . -type f -iname "aaa" OR "bbb"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fort these two names you can use:
 `find . -type f \( -iname 'aaa' -o -iname 'bbb' \) -print`.

Not that you do not need the `'` around the names if you just search for aaa or bbb, but you do need them if you use wildcards and do not want the shell to expand them.

Example with wildcards:
`find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.gif' \) -print`

Comment: What's the point of the `-print`? Isn't that the same as simply omitting it?

Comment: In many cases: yes. However just because that is the default on most find implementations means that omitting it will work everywhere or that it will continue to work in the future. Thus it is a good habit to explicitly state the option.  (Much like the dot in the OPs first command which you can omit as default on many, but not all implementations of find).

Comment: `.` is definitely good to have, no questions about it (for UNIX + BSD). Where have you seen a `find` that doesn't print without `-print`?

Comment: I _think_ HP-UX's `find` requires `-print`, but I no longer have access to an HP-UX system to check.